# Docker mount having dynamic file structure without restarting container

Tags: docker, filesystems, mount

Essentially I need a link from the host -> container by some mount. The scenario is for me to plug in any USB, and have udev/systemd create a mount directory on the host, and then have the container read the files on that, and then for me to be able to unplug the USB (all without restarting the container).

I tried a simple bind mount using `--mount type=bind,source="/media",target="/host_media"`, but when a mount directory is created on the host in `/media/usb-mount`, the change is not reflected in the container.

I then tried to create a Docker volume, and (manually) mounted a USB device from the host into the volume (eventually from a script spawned by udev/systemd), but the changes were not reflected either.

Obviously, if I start the container with or without the USB mounted, I can see the files, but as soon as the directory structure changes, the container does not take the changes.

How is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: This sounds like a process that's very intertwined with host devices and host services.  Can you run it directly on the host?  Adding an isolation layer like Docker will make it much harder to talk to the USB device, udev, and systemd, ignoring your mount issues.

Comment: Adding and removing mounts inside a mount point sounds like the situation where you need the obscure [bind propagation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation) settings, though; does changing the mount to `-v /media:/host_media:rshared` make a difference?

Comment: @DavidMaze Holy crap, that seems to have worked. I did read that section in the bind mounts for Docker, but I guess I didn't understand it enough to have tried it. But now, I can see the folder appearing/disappearing in the container when udev does the same for the host. Thank you so much!